# C++ std::List inserting between middle and end?

Tags: c++, list

If I have a basic list like this:

```
std::list<int> mylist;
mylist.push_front(1);
mylist.push_front(2);
mylist.push_front(3);
mylist.push_front(4);
mylist.push_front(5);
mylist.push_front(6);
mylist.push_front(7);
```

how would I insert the number 8 between the 3 and 4?

Comment: [`std::list::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert)

Comment: What happened to the documentation? Are all the websites down?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thank you for your extraordinary contribution. Much appreciated...

Comment: @user997112: Likewise, this question is a great addition to the Stack Overflow repository and we are forever in your debt. In all seriousness, though, if I'd managed to teach you how to use documentation and to perform research, it would be the best help you'd ever been given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using : [*`std::list::insert`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert) and [*`std::advance`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance)

```
auto it = mylist.begin();

std::advance(it,4); //locate the position
mylist.insert(it,8); //insert the element
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work if your list is sorted according to the comparison criterion as in your example. The list may also contain duplicates:

```
mylist.insert(std::upper_bound(mylist.rbegin(), mylist.rend(), 3).base(), 8);
```

`std::upper_bound` returns the iterator to the first position where the value compared is greater than `3` and `std::insert` inserts `8` at that position.

Comment: You should probably explain that this assumes a certain sorting of the list.